# GGplot 2 - geom_line x axis true-to-scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a geom_line plot of sample concentrations over time using ggplot2. The y-axis shows the concentration and the x-axis the time the sample was taken in hours.

Here is the dataset:

```
dput(data_M1_summary)
structure(list(Mean_M1.mg.mL. = c(2.02877, 1.88472, 1.975485, 
1.981743), Median_M1.mg.mL. = c(2.124, 2.043, 1.992, 1.981), 
Storage_time.h. = c("1", "12", "48", "72")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code I used to plot the line plot:

```
data_M1_summary$Mean_M1.mg.mL. <- as.numeric(data_M1_summary$Mean_M1.mg.mL.)
data_M1_summary$Median_M1.mg.mL. <- as.numeric(data_M1_summary$Median_M1.mg.mL.)
data_M1_summary

ggplot(data_M1_summary, aes(x=`Storage_time.h.`, y=Median_M1.mg.mL., fill=Storage_time.h.))+
geom_line(group=1, linetype= "dashed")+
geom_point()+
xlab("Storage time [h]")+
ylab("Median Concentration [mg/mL]")+
ggtitle(label = "Median Ampicillin degradation in Material 1 (PC+LSR-40)")+
theme_minimal()
```

[image: Example plot]

My problem is that the x-axis only shows the 4 distinct values "1 hr", "12 hr", "48 hr" and "72 hr" with equal spaces between each label. I want a true-to-scale x axis where the space between the labels reflects the time that has passed, i.e. distance between 1 and 12 hr is smaller than the distance between 12 and 48 hr.
Ideally, the x-axis would also show the hours in between, i.e. 1hr-5hr-10hr etc.

Comment: Try with converting Storage_time.h to a numeric. As it is a character you get a categorical axis.

Comment: @stefan thank you so much! What a stupid mistake I made there, I should have been able to solve this myself - thank you!